# +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Account''

Tags: ios, core-data, authentication, xcode5, keychain

I have tried a lot of options, but can't find the solution for this problem. I created a Core Data file and named the entity Account, Created an string attribute called username. Then edited the class of the entity to NSManagedObject, not sure if this is right. Now, the following code is in my LoginViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ITAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ITAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    Account *newAccount = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newAccount setValue:@"Jorge" forKey:@"username"];
    [newAccount setPassword:@"password"];

    NSLog(@"username:%@   password: %@", [newAccount username], [newAccount password]);

}
```

I followed [This Tutorial](http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/core-data-passwords-in-keychain/) and my code files look like this:

ITAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ITAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@end
```

ITAppDelegate.m

```
#import "ITAppDelegate.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@implementation ITAppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary    *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
if (_managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil)
{
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext  setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return _managedObjectContext;
}


- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
if (_managedObjectModel != nil)
{
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
return _managedObjectModel;
}


- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
{
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

@end
```

AccountBase.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface AccountBase : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *username;


@end
```

AccountBase.m

```
#import "AccountBase.h"

@implementation AccountBase

@dynamic username;

@end
```

Account.h

```
#import "AccountBase.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Account : AccountBase

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *password;

@end
```

Account.m

```
#import "Account.h"
#import "KeychainHelper.h"

@implementation Account

- (NSString*)password
{
    if (self.username)
        return [KeychainHelper getPasswordForKey:self.username];
    return nil;
}

- (void)setPassword:(NSString*)aPassword
{
    if (self.username)
        [KeychainHelper setPassword:aPassword forKey:self.username];
}

- (void)prepareForDeletion
{
    if (self.username)
        [KeychainHelper removePasswordForKey:self.username];
}
@end
```

KeychainHelper.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface KeychainHelper : NSObject

+ (NSString*)getPasswordForKey:(NSString*)aKey;
+ (void)setPassword:(NSString*)aPassword forKey:(NSString*)aKey;
+ (void)removePasswordForKey:(NSString*)aKey;

@end
```

KeychainHelper.m

```
#import "KeychainHelper.h"
#import <Security/Security.h>

@interface KeychainHelper ()
+ (NSMutableDictionary*)dictionaryForKey:(NSString*)aKey;
@end

@implementation KeychainHelper


static const NSString *ironTrainers = @"com.domain.myapplication";

+ (NSMutableDictionary*)dictionaryForKey:(NSString*)aKey
{
    NSData *encodedKey = [aKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [searchDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [searchDictionary setObject:encodedKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric];
    [searchDictionary setObject:encodedKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
    [searchDictionary setObject:ironTrainers forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrService];

    return searchDictionary;
}  

+ (NSString*)getPasswordForKey:(NSString*)aKey
{
    NSString *password = nil;

    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [self dictionaryForKey:aKey];
    [searchDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];
    [searchDictionary setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];

    CFTypeRef result = NULL;
    BOOL statusCode = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, &result);
    if (statusCode == errSecSuccess) {
        NSData *resultData = CFBridgingRelease(result);
        password = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    return (__bridge NSString *)(result);
}

+ (void)removePasswordForKey:(NSString*)aKey
{
    NSMutableDictionary *keyDictionary = [self dictionaryForKey:aKey];
    SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyDictionary);
 }

+ (void)setPassword:(NSString*)aPassword forKey:(NSString*)aKey
{
    [KeychainHelper removePasswordForKey:aKey];

    NSData *encodedPassword = [aPassword dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableDictionary *keyDictionary = [self dictionaryForKey:aKey];
    [keyDictionary setObject:encodedPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
    SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyDictionary, nil);
}

@end
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) return managedObjectContext;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {

        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}
```

- You haven't provided a lazy loading implementation of `persistentStoreCoordinator`
- so `coordinator` will always be `nil`
- so you will always be returning `nil` from this method
- which means you will always get the error above.

To explain the error:

> +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Account'

It's not immediately obvious from reading it, but this means that `nil` is not a legal thing to pass for the managed object context. On first reading, it looks like you're doing `entityForName:nil` but that isn't the case.

To fix the problem, you will need to provide a valid persistent store coordinator. I have a small article [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/09/07/the-core-data-stack/) which explains just how little code you need to set up a core data stack, this may help you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for the username. I changed app delegate (please see above), but now Im getting the error: -[NSManagedObject setPassword:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Well, that's a whole different question. That looks like you haven't defined the proper subclass in your data model (there's a "Name" and "Class" box to fill in)

Comment: My data model has one attribute which is username. And the entity name is Account, the class that shows there is NSManagedObject, which I edited earlier, not sure if that's right though.

Comment: You have to set the class to Account and generate the Account.h and Account.m files by selecting the entity and choosing editor --> create NSManagedObject subclass..

Comment: This is my output: username:Jorge   password: <70617373 776f7264>
I'm guessing it worked, right?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I'm using multiple contexts (parent/child) with different concurrency types to improve performance. I have three contexts:

1. `storeContext` which is the only context whose `persistentStoreCoordinator` had been set.
2. `viewContext` whose parent is `storeContext`
3. `backgroundContext` whose parent *should have been `viewContext`* but **I forgot to set `backgroundContext.parent = viewContext`**.

Saving an entity on the `backgroundContext` produced the same error...

> +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name...

...because `backgroundContext` wasn't a part of the parent/child context chain.

Setting `backgroundContext`'s `parent` to `viewContext` established the chain back to the persistent store coordinator and resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this `entityForName: nil` error, but it ended up being somewhat of a red herring that only manifested itself when running unit tests on my CI. During testing, the app was encountering some weird threading conditions caused by [NSAttributedString's HTML Importer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-init#discussion). An asynchronous dispatch onto the main queue to interact with Core Data was happening just as the `NSAttributedString` was being created from HTML.

Just posting my experience here in case it ends up helping someone else. :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error while fetching data from Core Data. The reason was value to context object was not set properly and It was setting to it after fetching the result. So, setting context properly before hitting fetch request makes the work done.

Answer (score 0):

Me using below fixes

Before
**NotesListModel.xcdatamodeld**

After I changed
**NotesList.xcdatamodeld**

NotesList name I have used for all places, but filename **NotesListModel**

That's why I'm facing this issue

It might happens because of mismatch of entity name and its class name. Ensure that your Account entity has an appropriate class name in **.xcdatamodeld** file.

Answer (score -1):

It might happens because of mismatch of entity name and its class name. Ensure that your Account entity has an appropriate class name in .xcdatamodeld file.

Comment: The error message states that the managedObjectContext parameter is nil, this is nothing to do with the model