# +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

**What I'm trying to do**: Get an NSFetchedResultsController to work for the first time to connect a UITableView to Core Data. I'm a newbie and really inexperienced, and I've followed [Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) word to word.

**The error**:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Medicine''`.
```

**What I tried:** None of the other StackOverflow questions that I found (including
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596487/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-core-data) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472465/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-searching-fo)) have the an explanation, except for [the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472465/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-searching-fo) which makes some sense. However, the method he mentioned is already written in my app delegate, which I imported in the TableViewController class I'm using.

**What I'd greatly appreciate**: An explanation of what I'm doing/what's gone wrong and how to fix it, rather than just the answer/correction.

### PMMedicinesTableViewController.m

```
#import "PMMedicinesTableViewController.h"
#import "PMAppDelegate.h"
#import "Medicine.h"

@interface PMMedicinesTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end


@implementation PMMedicinesTableViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }

}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Medicine" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    
    return _fetchedResultsController;
    
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id  sectionInfo =
    [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Medicine *med = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = med.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                 med.name];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"medicineCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // Set up the cell...
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is telling you that `self.managedObjectContext` is nil, which means that you haven't assigned a value to that property. Most likely you should have done this in whatever code created or loaded this view controller (e.g. in `prepareForSegue:sender:` if you're using storyboards).