# Accessing Shared Data from Two Apps

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, core-data, ios-app-group

Do you know how do to share Core Data with two Apps (whose you're owner) allowing read and write to the same .sqlite ?

I have tried to use App Groups :

1) 
    Bank.xcdatamodeld
    BankInfo.swift
    BankDetails.swift

I have copied those files into the directory for this app B's project  (retrieve from the app A's project ) and then I have dragged them into Xcode.

2) I have retrieved the sqlite file from the common sandbox of the app groups

***App Delegate : Core Data stack [Swift]***

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {

    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
    }()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {

    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("shareapps", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {


    // Create the coordinator and store

    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    let directory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("com.sd.shareapps");

    let url = directory?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("shareapps.sqlite")

    //Sarting frehs every time
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(url!, error: nil)

    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."

    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
    println("\(coordinator?.persistentStores)")
    return coordinator
    }()     
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {

    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

I have got this error message :

```
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Entity'"
```

Regards

Comment: When you create your managed object context, do you assign it a valid persistent store coordinator?  (What's the code for that look like?)

Comment: ```lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()```The app crashes without pass to my breakpoint in Core Data Stack. I don't sure to proceed to the good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

```
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Entity'"
```

gives the key to answering to this question. The error message is very similar in wording to `is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext...`, which was answered in a similar question [+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Account''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472465/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-searching-fo).

So although the error message is cryptic in both cases, in this case the error message means that somewhere in your code you are passing `nil` for the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. Setting breakpoints should help to determine where. I was able to reproduce the same error by making the following modifications to your code:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {  
    // normally we would initialize the persistentStoreCoordinator here
    // but to reproduce an error, just return nil
    return nil;
} 

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {

    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
          // normally, we would return nil right away if there is 
          // no coordinator, but to reproduce the error carry on anyway
//        if coordinator == nil {
//            return nil
//        }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

For anyone else reading this answer, note that the Core Data stack will never be used (the lazy variables will not be initialized) unless we do something useful with Core Data. In the sample application I created to reproduce this error message, I just left the Core Data stack in place (the Xcode template puts it in the App Delegate), and then I tried to create an entity inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        var context : NSManagedObjectContext? = self.managedObjectContext

        // the line below will cause an exception when the
        // NSPersistentStoreCoordinator is nil
        var entity : NSEntityDescription? = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Entity", 
           inManagedObjectContext:context!)

        return true
    }
```

Note that the code provided in the original post did not cause any error. Possibly the code in the posted question does not match the actual code used in the project, or possibly elsewhere in the application there is a managed object context created with a nil persistent store coordinator. Regardless, the cryptic error message has been deciphered.

You may wish to make sure that you have set up your shared app group properly. See this article (http://jasoncross-ios-development.blogspot.com/2015/04/accessing-shared-data-between-ios.html) which covers setting up a shared app group using entitlements.