# how to add core data support ios 9 & ios 10 objective c xcode 8.3

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios9, ios10, xcode8

I've created a new project Using Xcode 8.3.2 with core data.
 It's running on iOS 10 but gives error when try to run same on iOS 9.

App delegate provided core data stack and saving support methods  automatically.

```
@synthesize persistentContainer = _persistentContainer;

- (NSPersistentContainer *)persistentContainer {
    // The persistent container for the application. This implementation creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the application to it.
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (_persistentContainer == nil) {
            _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"coreDataExample"];
            [_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                    /*
                     Typical reasons for an error here include:
                     * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                     * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                     * The device is out of space.
                     * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                    */
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                    abort();
                }
            }];
        }
    }

    return _persistentContainer;
}


- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        abort();
    }
}
```

After that I'm trying to save some data but it gives me error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'FOODCATEGORIES''

Here is code for saving data

```
 -(void)addCategoryToDB:(NSArray*)items{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =  self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
    for(NSInteger i=0;i<items.count;i++){
        NSManagedObject *tmpCategory = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:CORE_DATA_TABLE_CATEGORIES inManagedObjectContext:context];
        FoodCategory* item= [items objectAtIndex:i];
        [tmpCategory setValue:item.name forKey:@"name"];
        [tmpCategory setValue:item.url forKey:@"url"];
        [tmpCategory setValue:item.stripColorCode forKey:@"stripColorCode"];
        [tmpCategory setValue:item.postion forKey:@"position"];
        [tmpCategory setValue:item.buttonImage forKey:@"buttonImage"];
        [self saveContext];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try by deleting app from simulator. Have you created "FOODCATEGORIES" entiry?

Comment: If you build your app with core data model and then made changes in entities you need to delete an app on device or simulator and then rebuild. Also, you could do core data model versions and after each change, you will need to build with new version of core data.

Comment: Where is the method `addCategoryToDB` located?  what is `self` pointing to in that method?  If it is not the appDelegate then `self.persistentContainer` is nil.

Comment: it is in appDelegate & running fine on iphone 6s

Comment: hey @nazir its new app with new core data file

Comment: does putting `[self persistentContainer]` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` fix it?

Comment: the problem is Xcode 8.3 created different core data stack from data stack created in xcode version prior to 8 . So the problem outcomes .

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that self.managedObjectContext is nil, which means that you haven't assigned a value to that property. Most likely you should have done this in whatever code created or loaded this view controller (e.g. in prepareForSegue:sender: if you're using storyboards).

The following Link may help you [clickHere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472465/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-searching-fo)