# +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'AppData'

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

The persistant container goes nil. When I run program I get this error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'AppData'

I have found similar questions on stackoverflow but haven't got any problem solving answer that is why I'm posting this question again.

Here is my code :

```
-(void)saveData
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext=((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).persistentContainer.viewContext;
//    [self initPer];



//    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
//    AppDelegate *delg = (AppDelegate *)app.delegate;
//    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = delg.getManagedObj;
//    AppData *appData1= [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AppData" inManagedObjectContext:localContext];



//    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = _del.persistentContainer.viewContext;
    AppData *appDta = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AppData" inManagedObjectContext:localContext];


    NSString *value = [valueArray1 componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    NSString *commandKey = [keyArray1 componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dictionary setObject:value forKey: nsDate];

    NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);


    appDta.key = commandKey;
    appDta.details = dictionary;

}
```

AppDelegate.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong) NSPersistentContainer *persistentContainer;

- (void)saveContext;

-(NSManagedObjectContext*)getManagedObj;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}


-(NSManagedObjectContext*)getManagedObj{
    return self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

@synthesize persistentContainer = _persistentContainer;

- (NSPersistentContainer *)persistentContainer {
    // The persistent container for the application. This implementation creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the application to it.
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (_persistentContainer == nil) {
            _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"Model"];
            [_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                    /*
                     Typical reasons for an error here include:
                     * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                     * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                     * The device is out of space.
                     * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                    */
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                    abort();
                }
            }];
        }
    }

    return _persistentContainer;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        abort();
    }
}
```

You can see that some lines are commented, I kept it to show that I've also tried it but haven't got any result.

Comment: `localContext` is `nil` try debugging it

Comment: Show Your `AppDelegate` Code for `CoreData`.

Comment: @PrasadPatil Not in comment Edit your question.

Comment: @PiyushPatel : I'll add AppDelegate code in question.

Comment: @PiyushPatel: Yah I was doing that but I added it here by mistake.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this error from 4-5 days. Sometime it works fine but some time it crash and gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472465/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-searching-fo?rq=1)

Set

AppDelegate.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong) NSPersistentContainer *persistentContainer;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;


- (void)saveContext;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)getManagedObj;
```

AppDelegate.m :

```
#pragma mark - Core Data stack

@synthesize persistentContainer = _persistentContainer;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;


- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"DB Path==> %@",storeURL);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {
        // Report any error we got.
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)getManagedObj {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Then try with your commented code like as under :

```
    AppDelegate *objAppDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [objAppDel managedObjectContext];
    AppData *objAppData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AppData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Comment: Hay, thank you but now here coordinator is going nil.

Comment: @PrasadPatil Follow this tutorial that will help you : http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/

Comment: @PrasadPatil Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: I tried doing this but I got this error : error:  Cannot load NSManagedObjectModel.  nil is an illegal URL parameter
CoreData: error:  Cannot load NSManagedObjectModel.  nil is an illegal URL parameter
2017-06-19 14:53:40.630 Remember Bot-POC[93303:444563] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'CoreData: Cannot load NSManagedObjectModel.  nil is an illegal URL parameter'

Comment: And I tried doing the changes shown in the tutorial but it remains in the managedObjectContext function loop.