# entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Leads'' when using real ipad

Tags: objective-c, core-data

im working with coredata, everything is well when using an iphone, but when trying the app on a real ipad,im getting the error above,
my code:

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context =   ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).persistentContainer.viewContext;
    NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Leads" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

knowing that its working fine using iphone, its saving the data and retrieving it, this problem only occurred when i used a real ipad, ipad simulator works normally.
any idea whats going around?

Comment: To my knowledge, CoreData acts the same way on iPhone and iPad, so I would rather look in other differences between the two. Maybe you have different behaviours depending on the device you are building on?

Comment: Did you take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472465/entityforname-nil-is-not-a-legal-nsmanagedobjectcontext-parameter-searching-fo)?

Comment: yes i did, and i tried the solution suggested there, but it didnt work

Comment: Then I think you should  find out what's different between the two environments you are building on. For example, are there any device-related (such as "ifdef ipad") directives anywhere in the app, that might interfere with that context?

Comment: Please remove the error message from the title and add it to the question as a block, using `>`, so that the title gets easier to read and so that the exact error message is displayed clearly.

Comment: this issue is only on real ipad devices, if i use ipad simulator, it goes fine.